# How to scrape dynamic sports website created on toggle button with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/men/2024-school-stats.html, and grab the "per game" stats, which requires the user to toggle on/off, in order to show info in table. I am able to scrape the total stats, but am struggling to figure out how to scrape the per-game stats, since it requires toggle on/off within the table.

Do I have to use Selenium + BeautifulSoup? Or am I able to accomplish this with just BeautifulSoup4? (I am a novice who knows enough to build a simple scraper but this is a bit beyond my reach.) Thanks for any help!

This is what I've tried so far...

```
!pip install requests beautifulsoup4 pandas

import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def scrape_team_stats(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Attempt to find the table with the specific class
    table = soup.find('table', class_='modified')
    if not table:
        # If the specific table is not found, fall back to finding any table
        table = soup.find('table')

    if not table:
        return []  # Return an empty list if no table is found

    # Extracting team data
    team_stats = []
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        # Find the per-game stats using data-stat attributes
        team_name = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'school_name'})
        fg_percentage = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'fg_pct'})
        orb_per_game = row.find('td', {'class': 'right modified' }, {'data-stat': 'orb'})
        ast_per_game = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'ast'})
        stl_per_game = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'stl'})
        blk_per_game = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'blk'})
        tov_per_game = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'tov'})
        pf_per_game = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'pf'})

        if team_name:
            team_stats.append([
                team_name.text.strip(),
                fg_percentage.text.strip() if fg_percentage else 'N/A',
                orb_per_game.text.strip() if orb_per_game else 'N/A',
                ast_per_game.text.strip() if ast_per_game else 'N/A',
                stl_per_game.text.strip() if stl_per_game else 'N/A',
                blk_per_game.text.strip() if blk_per_game else 'N/A',
                tov_per_game.text.strip() if tov_per_game else 'N/A',
                pf_per_game.text.strip() if pf_per_game else 'N/A'
            ])

    return team_stats

def write_to_csv(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Team', 'FG%', 'ORB/G', 'AST/G', 'STL/G', 'BLK/G', 'TOV/G', 'PF/G'])  # Writing header
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)

url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/men/2024-school-stats.html'
team_stats = scrape_team_stats(url)
csv_filename = 'team_per_game_stats.csv'
write_to_csv(team_stats, csv_filename)

print(f"Data has been written to {csv_filename}")
```

Comment: Your question should contain (a small but representative sample of) the HTML you are trying to parse. We should not have to visit the site in order to see it, and besides, it is likely to change over time, which means the question will be useless without a copy of what you actually saw. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Needed a MCVE - have to visit the site in order to answer it, which also makes it a spam candidate. No value lost if deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Selenium if you don't need to. Much quicker to get the data from the requests. The "Per Game" toggle is just javascript that takes the given columns and divides by games. you can do that easily with pandas.

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/men/2024-school-stats.html'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]

df['Rk'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rk'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Rk'])

cols = ['Tm.', 'Opp.', 'MP', 'FG', 'FGA',
'3P', '3PA', 'FT', 'FTA', 'ORB', 'TRB', 'AST', 'STL',
'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF']

df[['G'] + cols] = df[['G'] + cols].astype(int)

df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['G'], axis=0)
```

### Output:

```
print(df.head().to_string())
    Rk             School   G  W   L  W-L%     SRS    SOS  Unnamed: 8  W.1  L.1  Unnamed: 11 W.2 L.2  Unnamed: 14 W.3 L.3  Unnamed: 17        Tm.       Opp.  Unnamed: 20         MP         FG        FGA   FG%         3P        3PA   3P%         FT        FTA   FT%        ORB        TRB        AST       STL       BLK        TOV         PF
0  1.0  Abilene Christian  12  5   7  .417   -3.40   0.60         NaN    0    2          NaN   2   3          NaN   1   3          NaN  75.750000  75.166667          NaN  40.416667  25.666667  58.916667  .436   5.583333  17.000000  .328  18.833333  26.166667  .720   9.750000  33.750000  13.833333  8.333333  1.416667  13.583333  20.916667
1  2.0          Air Force  12  7   5  .583   -4.31  -8.48         NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   4   3          NaN   3   1          NaN  69.166667  65.000000          NaN  40.416667  24.083333  52.166667  .462   8.583333  23.833333  .360  12.416667  18.250000  .680   7.000000  31.666667  15.583333  7.916667  5.000000  12.583333  16.666667
2  3.0              Akron  11  8   3  .727    3.29   0.51         NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   5   0          NaN   2   1          NaN  78.272727  66.818182          NaN  40.454545  27.454545  58.090909  .473   9.545455  26.636364  .358  13.818182  19.090909  .724  11.090909  36.909091  15.545455  6.545455  2.545455  13.272727  15.454545
3  4.0            Alabama  12  7   5  .583   24.55   9.89         NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   6   1          NaN   0   1          NaN  92.166667  77.500000          NaN  40.000000  30.750000  63.333333  .486  11.250000  29.500000  .381  19.416667  25.083333  .774  12.750000  39.750000  16.083333  7.666667  4.333333  11.583333  19.166667
4  5.0        Alabama A&M  12  1  11  .083  -18.58  -0.49         NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   1   2          NaN   0   8          NaN  69.750000  87.833333          NaN  40.416667  23.250000  58.916667  .395   4.000000  16.000000  .250  19.250000  26.666667  .722  12.000000  34.500000   9.750000  8.250000  3.250000  15.666667  21.666667
```

Comment: Oh wow, this works excellent too! Thank you very much! This definitely chops it down and makes it easier. When running this code, I get the entire table, is there a way to only scrape the particular columns I am looking for? Thank you! @chitown88

Comment: I just figured it out...all set! Thank you again! Less is more, and keep Selenium out of the equation helps tremendously with this workaround.
`cols = ['Tm.', 'Opp.', 'MP', 'FG', 'FGA',
        '3P', '3PA', 'FT', 'FTA', 'ORB', 'TRB', 'AST', 'STL',
        'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF']

df[['G'] + cols] = df[['G'] + cols].astype(int)

df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['G'], axis=0)

# Write only the specified columns to CSV
df[cols].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use `Selenium` to emulate toggle button pressing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
driver.get('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/men/2024-school-stats.html')
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'basic_school_stats_per_match_toggle')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
html_source = driver.page_source
```

After that you can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse `html_source` content.

Comment: Boom!! You are awesome! This worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your quick, accurate response and help! I will certainly have to pay this forward along my Python journey! For those viewing this answer, I adjusted these lines after implementing @Alderven answer: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')` [swapped out *response.txt* for *html_source*]. `def scrape_team_stats()` [removed *(url)*]. `team_stats = scrape_team_stats()` [removed *(url)*]